# VS code keeps requiring me to resave file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I try and run any file I prompts me to "save as". If I click save it runs, and if I click cancel it also runs. The file has been saved. I have reset my settings, uninstalled and reinstalled and more. I can't figure out why this is happening[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you are looking for.

```
Settings > Features > Debug > Save Before Start > none
```

I have set it as "allEditorsInActiveGroup", which means, it auto-saves the files before running them. If you want it to be auto-saved use this option.

Setting it as "none" runs the file with the previously saved changes.